# What's this error in marklogic logs - XDMP-FORESTNOT , SVC-FILWRT, Invalid argument

Tags: marklogic

ML version - `8.0-6.3`

`ErrorLog.txt` has the following errors:

> 2019-07-06 02:50:27.393 Notice: rsuite-xdbc: XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest
>   forest-f4 not available: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in checkpoint of forest
>   forest-f4: SVC-FILWRT: File write error: write
>   'D:\MarkLogic\Forests\forest-f4\Journals\Journal-20190705-154854-149559215-15623417344051124-12863660834980579462':
>   Invalid argument
>
> 2019-07-06 02:50:27.645 Notice: rsuite-xdbc: XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest
>   forest-f4 not available: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in checkpoint of forest
>   forest-f4: SVC-FILWRT: File write error: write
>   'D:\MarkLogic\Forests\forest-f4\Journals\Journal-20190705-154854-149559215-15623417344051124-12863660834980579462':
>   Invalid argument

Searched in google but no gain.
Please help me understand this error.

After restarting the Marklogic I don't see this error but I am curious to know the reason behind this error.

**Update:**

I could see these errors as well in the log file.

> XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in checkpoint of forest rsuite-f5: XDMP-MEMORY:
>   Memory exhausted 2019-07-10 16:39:09.250 Notice: rsuite-xdbc:
>   XDMP-MEMORY: Memory exhausted

which memory is exhaused, RAM or DISK?

DISK has almost 800GB free space.

Answer (score 1):

The first error indicates that for some reason the forest is not available, the second error indicates what operation failed.

On Windows based systems, errors like this can sometimes be caused by anti-virus scanning of the MarkLogic data directories.  Ensure the data directories are excluded from scanning.

Comment: There is no anti-virus installed on the machine! Any other possible reason?

Comment: @DixitSingla Not sure.  I would suggest enabling `debug` logging mode, and take look at the logs after the error occurs.  It may give you more information about what is going on.  Additionally, you can use Windows Process Monitor and use it to determine what's going on from the OS side for those processes and files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon